# What do windows "interface names" look like?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

There is a function called if_nametoindex() that converts an interface name into an interface index. This function appears to be available on Linux and Windows. On Linux, I imagine these interface names might look like "eth0" or "wlan0".

My question is: what do Win32 interface names look like? And are there any calls that let me query what interface names are available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's also `if_indextoname`.  I've added the output below.  This style of name (e.g. `loopback_0`) is not *the* Win32 interface name.  I guess these names only exist for compatibility with rfc2553.  Win32 actually uses interface names like `\DEVICE\TCPIP_{846EE342-7039-11DE-9D20-806E6F6E6963}`.

To enumerate all the interfaces you need to use `GetIfTable` and friends.  `if_nameindex` is not supported.

```
loopback_0
tunnel_0
tunnel_2
tunnel_3
ppp_0
ethernet_0
ethernet_1
ethernet_4
ppp_1
wireless_0
ethernet_9
tunnel_4
tunnel_1
tunnel_7
tunnel_8
wireless_5
tunnel_5
tunnel_9
tunnel_10
tunnel_6
wireless_1
wireless_2
ethernet_2
ethernet_3
ethernet_5
ethernet_6
ethernet_7
wireless_3
wireless_4
wireless_6
wireless_7
wireless_8
```

Answer (score 2):

They look like `\Device\NPF_{506B4345-1FC0-43F4-BFCF-4FFAD7739AFF}`.  I don't know if there's a more direct way to get a list of interfaces, but I got this one from wireshark, which uses [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need just to have a look at your interfaces, you can use the following command on the command prompt or in the new terminal.

```
netsh int ipv4 show interfaces
```

It simply displays the list of available IPv4-compliant interfaces (which are currently the most used).

Answer (score -1):

getmac
will list them at the Windows command prompt

Comment: On my Windows 10, with this command I can only see my mac address